# how can i resolve 500 internal server error on nginx server for node in case of location rewrite

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-location

> I have configured nginx server on my system, server was successfully configured and running well.
>
> *one/single node application running well*
>
> **but multiple application not running!!!**
>
> I am running multiple node application
> like:
>
> > "test1"
> > `http://127.0.0.1:3000`
> > "test2"
> > `http://127.0.0.1:3001`
> > "test3"
> > `http://127.0.0.1:3002`

in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;

   location / {
     proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:3000";
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }
}
```

**working well for one site.**

> but when i added on that file for multiple sites

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  location /test1{
    rewrite ^/test1(.*) $1 break;
    proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:3000";
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

> but i got `500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: The error log should give you information about the internal server error.

Comment: Can you attach the error log in Nginx or Node.js?

Comment: ok.. thanks i got solution....

```location /chat-app {
  rewrite ^/chat-app(.*) $1 break;
  proxy_pass "http://localhost:6060";
}```
and in url 
`http://localhost/test1/`